# Can´t make Qt, Visual C++2015 and openCV work together in 64bit

Tags: visual-studio, qt, opencv, 64-bit

I´m having trouble with a very simple console project. I am using latest version of MSVC 2015, openCV 3.2 an Qt 5.71 all in 64bit and windows 10 64bit.

The Qt .pro file is:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += main.cpp
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\OpenCV3.2\opencv\build\include" \
    CONFIG(debug,debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L"C:\OpenCV3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib" \
            -lopencv_world320d
    }
    CONFIG(release,debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L"C:\OpenCV3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib" \
            -lopencv_world320
    }
}
```

and the source code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\\core\\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\\highgui\\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\\imgproc\\imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat imLena; //<-- INCLUDING THIS LINE MAKE THE PROGRAM CRASH

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This simple program compiles an run perfectly but when I add de line "Mat  imLena;" it still compiles perfectly but crashes when I run it. I am very confused. Any tip, idea or suggestion?

Comment: Obviously the runtime cannot find some OpenCV DLL to initialize that cv::Mat object.

Comment: For crash issues you need to include -- at minimum -- the type of crash and the stack trace.

Comment: try adding C:\OpenCV3.2\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin to your PATH variable and remove any other opencv path from the PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. Elementary path problem. AlexanderVX was rigth.